# Random rotation happening, I don't get it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a scene that is as follows:
I have the player object, which is a Z locked cube that I move around with a script, using various AddForce calls. The important method in there is this one:

```
public void SetDirections(Vector3 down)
    {
    down.Normalize();
    this.down = down;
    forward = Vector3.Cross(down, new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
    }
```

Other code relating to rotation in the same script is this:

```
void Turning ()
    {
    // Irányitó gombok hatására a Taxi elforduljon 180fokot
    Vector3 lookDirection = forward;

    // balra forditás
    if (inputh > 0)
        {
        faceLeft = false;
        }

    // jobbra forditás
    if (inputh < 0)
        {
        faceLeft = true;
        }

    if (faceLeft)
        {
        lookDirection *= -1;
        }

    transform.LookAt(transform.position + lookDirection, new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
    }
```

I have this bit on another object in the scene:

```
public class RotateGravity : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Taxi;
public float MinLimit, MaxLimit;
private TaxiController tControl;
private Rigidbody tRigidbody;
private Transform tTransform;

void Start()
    {
    tControl = Taxi.GetComponent<TaxiController>();
    tRigidbody = Taxi.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    tTransform = Taxi.GetComponent<Transform>();
    }


void OnTriggerStay()
    {
    Vector3 originalDown = tControl.Down;
    Vector3 newDown = tTransform.position - gameObject.transform.position;

    if (Vector3.SignedAngle(newDown, new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 1)) > MinLimit &&
        Vector3.SignedAngle(newDown, new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, 1)) < MaxLimit)
        {
        newDown.Normalize();
        tControl.SetDirections(newDown);
        float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(originalDown, newDown, new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
        tRigidbody.velocity = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, new Vector3(0, 0, 1)) * tRigidbody.velocity;
        }

    Debug.Log("Stay: " + newDown);
    }

void OnTriggerExit()
    {
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(tTransform.position - gameObject.transform.position, new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    Vector3 newDown;
    float newAngle;
    
    if (Mathf.Abs(angle - MinLimit) < Mathf.Abs(angle - MaxLimit))
        {
        newDown = Quaternion.AngleAxis(MinLimit, new Vector3(0, 0, -1)) * new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        newAngle = MinLimit;
        }
        else
        {
        newDown = Quaternion.AngleAxis(MaxLimit, new Vector3(0, 0, -1)) * new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        newAngle = MaxLimit;
        }

    Debug.Log("Exit: " + newDown + " " + newAngle);

    tControl.SetDirections(newDown);
    tRigidbody.velocity = Quaternion.AngleAxis(newAngle, new Vector3(0, 0, 1)) * tRigidbody.velocity;
    }
}
```

Basically the idea is that the gravity direction changes as the player moves along the object, so just by moving right it would revolve around the object between the MinLimit and MaxLimit angles. Which it does. At the end I want to fix the direction to these limits and this is where a weird thing happens. In my example I have the MinLimit at 0 and the MaxLimit at 90. Meaning that the player enters horizontally from the left, and gravity changes from (0, -1, 0) to (1, 0, 0). Except, at the end the player object rotates 90 degrees around its forward vector.

Can somebody explain where I'm going wrong? I hate rotations in Unity :(

In the video below the red sphere is just an indicator under the player object to show better its facing.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4p9UQb7inA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was not setting the up vector correctly in the Turning() method, it pointed in the positive Y direction, so when my forward direction ended up being the same it didn't know where to rotate the object on that axis. I'm dumb. I set the up vector to point to -1 * down, and boom, it worked.

Comment: So what if the forward points down now wouldn't it be the same issue then?

Comment: No, because the variable down contains the current direction of the gravity for the player, which is not the same as (0, -1, 0), which you might be thinking of. So at the end there down contains a rightward pointing vector.